# Combining 3 Tables with Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

```
<?php foreach ($category_features as $category_feature):?>
    <?php if( $category_feature['form_type'] == 'text' ){?>
        <div class="six wide field">
            <label><?php echo $category_feature['feauture'];?></label>
            <input type="text" name="name-<?php echo $category_feature['id']?>">
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if( $category_feature['form_type'] == 'select' ){?>
        <div class="six wide field">
            <label><?php echo $category_feature['feauture'];?></label>
            <select name="name-<?php echo $category_feature['id']?>">
                <option value="">Choose</option>
                <?php foreach ($feauture_values as $feauture_value):?>
                <!-- how can i get the features' values  -->
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </select>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

As you see, I get the category features from a table and loop. And then a feature maybe selectbox so options are in another table. For every feature which is selectbox, I need to get that feature values which means options.. How can I create an SQL for this?

**features

`id  | feature  | form_type`

**category_features

`id  | feature_id  | category_id`

**feature_values

`id  |  feature_value  |  feature_id`

My tables are like that. According to category_id, I get the features. And I want to get also options if form_type is selectbox.

Comment: What was your initial query, what is the structures of your tables and what do you intend to select?

Comment: @LajosArpad I edited.

Comment: Why not just query the table for the select list inside the IF for the select type?

Comment: I wanted to answer this question, but it is not needed, since a good answer was already given.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it needs two steps to obtain the data structure that you want.

first, using the SQL like this

```
select 
f.from_type,
f.feature,
fv.feature_id,
fv.feature_value
 from features as f
inner join category_features as cf
on f.id = cf.feature_id
right join feature_values as fv;
```

and then aggregate the record set, maybe like following code

```
$result = [];

array_map(function (item) use (&$result) {
    // do some aggregate operations
}, $records);
```

it's hard to get correct result at one time